# Access subplot axes returned by pandas.DataFrame.plot()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

Is there a way I can access the axes returned by `pandas.DataFrame.plot(subplots=True)`? I'd like to give each plot a title (and access other attributes), but my current attempts only affect the last subplot.

```
svv[['Flow2 L/s','GWT','DOC mg/L', 'Hgtot ng/L', 'MeHg ng/L']].dropna().plot(subplots=True, figsize=(20, 20)) 
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax[0].set_title('title1') # Doesn't alter any of the plots
ax[1].set_title('title2') # Doesn't alter any of the plots
plt.title('5 plots') # Title appears above the last plot
```

I have also tried using `matplotlib.subplots()` to create the subplots individually but this lead to the shared x-axis no longer only by at the intersection of all the `Series` being plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Returned" means it is the result of the call to `plot`.  You can just store it in a variable:

```
ax = svv[['Flow2 L/s','GWT','DOC mg/L', 'Hgtot ng/L', 'MeHg ng/L']].dropna().plot(subplots=True, figsize=(20, 20))
```